# Importing a Typescript Module that has a constructor

Tags: javascript, typescript, knockout.js

I want to break up my file into several modules.  One module has a constructor.  I am able to import my module into another file, but I don't know how call my constructor in the new file.

```
namespace CreditReports{
  export class CreditReportVM {
        //some code

    constructor(targetElement: HTMLElement) {
        ko.applyBindings(this, targetElement);
        this.init();
     }

    public init = () => {
        //some code
     }

  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need to export the namespace too.

```
export namespace CreditReports {
    //...
}
```

Then when you want to call the constructor:

```
import { CreditReports } from "./my-module";

//...

new CreditReports.CreditReportVM(myElement);
```

You should replace `"./my-module"` with the file name (an path too) where your typescript module is in.

Comment: I'll give it a try.  Thanks much!

Comment: @user1647160 No problem. You can also mark my answer as answered if it worked for you. Thanks.